# PhoneGap Blackberry build error. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: blackberry, ant, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I am new to using PhoneGap and am trying to setup the example app, i'm using PhoneGap version 2.9.0 and apache-ant-1.9.1.

I have configured apache ant, installed the WebWorks SDK and have setup the project.properties file.

The error seems to be that it cannot find the 'CordovaExample' file in the temporary folder, i have checked the folder and it has the following files in it: 'CordovaExample.jdp', 'CordovaExample.jdw' and 'CordovaExample.rapc' (among various others). Am i missing some configuration so that it should search for one of these 3 files, instead of just 'CordovaExample'?

The error is shown below when the 'ant blackberry build' command is run:

```
jamest@JT1 /c/Development/FirstApp
$ ant blackberry build
Buildfile: c:\Development\FirstApp\build.xml

blackberry:

build:

generate-cod-name:
     [echo] Generated name: CordovaExample.cod

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory c:\Development\FirstApp\build

package-app:
    [mkdir] Created dir: c:\Development\FirstApp\build\widget
     [copy] Copying 22 files to c:\Development\FirstApp\build\widget
      [zip] Building zip: c:\Development\FirstApp\build\CordovaExample.zip

build:
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing command line options
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing bbwp.properties
     [exec] [INFO]                      Validating application archive
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing config.xml
     [exec] [INFO]                      Populating application source
     [exec] [INFO]                      Compiling BlackBerry WebWorks application
     [exec] I/O Error: C:\Users\jamest\AppData\Local\Temp\widgetGen.584154969137
3014448670.tmp\CordovaExample (The system cannot find the file specified)
     [exec] [ERROR]                     RAPC exception occurred

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 8 seconds
```

I've searched the web, but can't find any similar questions so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: perhaps [this link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/PhoneGap-Cordova-example-app-not-launching-in-BB10-Simulator/td-p/2072971) will give you an insight, what is going on.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help, as far as i'm aware the Blackberry WebWorks has installed correctly (i have installed/uninstalled multiple times to be sure), i am using the latest version and the project.properties file is pointing to the correct location. i'm not sure if its any different, but they're trying to build for blackberry 10 whereas i'm trying for blackberry smartphones (v7 and less). Thanks for the input though! any other thoughts?

Comment: have you asked your question on official blackberry support forum? There are many BlackBerry developers and I think you can get answer there much more faster. Here is the link: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/bd-p/browser_dev

Comment: i'll give it a try on there - had assumed that stackoverflow would have a better response time, but maybe the blackberry developers keep to themselves a bit more!

Comment: it depends. Sometimes BlackBerry support forums give answer faster than SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that you are using JDK 6 and **NOT JDK 7** - WebWorks requires that version [according to the BB support forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Error-in-building-BB7-app-RAPC-Exception/td-p/2436739):

> Please note that you need JDK6 (32-bit) to be installed and referenced
>   by the tools. Based on the sample it seems to be referencing JDK7.
>
> If you do not require JDK7 explicitly, the safest option is to
>   uninstall all existing JDK/JREs from your PC (this includes both
>   64-bit and 32-bit) versions from Program Files and Program Files
>   (x86); respectively. And then install only JDK6 (which automatically
>   includes the JRE) that is 32-bit.

Apparently you might even need a specific build of JDK 6:

> I noticed that JDK1.6 build 43 had the same behaviour during the
>   packaging process [...]
>
> I had to roll back to JDK1.6 build 30 before I could sign and package
>   my webworks apps again.

Comment: thanks, this was the issue - rolling back to JDK1.6 build 30 worked.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with JDK1.6 build 43. anything later than that and i got errors.  
You also need to ensure that you reference the correct version within the bbwp.properties file (C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5\bin\bbwp.properties). This seems to get set when you install WebWorks and doesn't use the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 4):

First time I also Face same problem :-

To solve it :-
I use following step:-

1. Move to JDK 1.7 to JDK 1.6
2. follow the process as per this link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html
3. Modify .properties file
4. use signtool to sign the app using keys
5. then you will get Install able files

Comment: Still i got the err in blackberry set up ....[Error: blackberry-nativepackager cannot be found on the path. Aborting.
]